# D3 Append Text with X Inline Images

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas

I want to append a text that can have X number of inline images to an SVG.

The idea is that the text would be interpolated from `Test [img1] the total [img2]` to `Test <img src="img1.png" /> the total <img src="img2.png" />`. The interpolation function is already working as intended.

After interpolating the text, I want it to append to the parent SVG properly.

Currently, I have:

```
// Desc
nodeEnter.append("text")
    .text(d => parseDesc(d))
    .attr("y", 131)
    .attr("x", 7);

...

function parseDesc(d) {
   const interpolate = (string, values) => string.replace(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g, (match, offset) => {
      ...
   });
   ...
   return interpolate(d.data.description, replacements).replaceAll("\\n","<br/>").split('\n');
}
```

Which appends:

```
Test [object HTMLImageElement] the total [object HTMLImageElement]
```

to my parent SVG.

Any way to display the images properly rather than the [object HTMLImageElement] tag?

Edit:
I have thought about having parseDesc return a canvas, however, the Canvas element has the same problem.. Returning `[object HTMLImageElement]` in place of the image. The code I would be using for a canvas append, if that is easier to append, would be:

```
// Desc
nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
   .attr("xlink:href", d => parseDesc(d))
   .attr("y", 131)
   .attr("x", 7);

...

function parseDesc(d) {
   const interpolate = (string, values) => string.replace(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g, (match, offset) => {
      ...
   });
   ...
   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.width = 115;
   canvas.height = 65;

   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.font = "bolder 9.4pt";
   const x = 10;
   const y = 10;
   const lineheight = 1.6;
   const lines = interpolate(d.data.description, replacements).replaceAll("\\n","<br/>").split('\n');
   for (var i = 0; i<lines.length; i++)
      ctx.fillText(lines[i], x, y + (i * lineheight));

   return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

This method, however, feels a LOT more hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are appending as text it is converting html element to string. What you could do is append a foreignObject and use `.html`, this should append the value returned from `parseDesc` as html and hence show the image properly.

```
nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
    .html(d => parseDesc(d))
    .attr("y", 131)
    .attr("x", 7);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Binabh/5xds8ybn/19/) is a minimal fiddle showing it working where text and image are showing together in the same line inside a d3 svg.